# Как подобрать нулевое значение для базовых типов в шаблоне?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как подобрать значение для базовых типов `int32_t`, `int8_t` и т.д. для шаблонного класса?

Т.е. что бы в методе `const bool is_empty() const noexcept;` возвращалась проверка что оба поля равны нулю, `.0f`, `0ui32`, `0i32` и т.д.

Или можно как-то в шаблон передать значение для сравнения?

```
template <typename __type>
class point_base
{
    point_base() noexcept;
    virtual ~point_base() noexcept;

    point_base(point_base const&) noexcept;
    point_base(point_base&&) noexcept;

    point_base& operator=(point_base const&) noexcept;
    point_base& operator=(point_base&&) noexcept;

    const __type x() const noexcept;
    const __type y() const noexcept;

    void set_x(const __type x) noexcept;
    void set_y(const __type y) noexcept;

    const bool is_empty() const noexcept;

protected:
    __type m_x_;
    __type m_y_;
};

template<typename __type>
inline point_base<__type>::point_base() noexcept :
    m_x_{},
    m_y_{} {}

template<typename __type>
inline point_base<__type>::~point_base() noexcept = default;

template<typename __type>
inline point_base<__type>::point_base(point_base const&) noexcept = default;

template<typename __type>
inline point_base<__type>::point_base(point_base&&) noexcept = default;

template<typename __type>
inline point_base<__type>& point_base<__type>::operator=(point_base const&) noexcept = default;

template<typename __type>
inline point_base<__type>& point_base<__type>::operator=(point_base&&) noexcept = default;

template<typename __type>
inline const __type point_base<__type>::x() const noexcept
{
    return m_x_;
}

template<typename __type>
inline const __type point_base<__type>::y() const noexcept
{
    return m_y_;
}

template<typename __type>
inline void point_base<__type>::set_x(const __type x) noexcept
{
    m_x_ = x;
}

template<typename __type>
inline void point_base<__type>::set_y(const __type y) noexcept
{
    m_y_ = y;
}

template<typename __type>
inline const bool point_base<__type>::is_empty() const noexcept
{
    // выполнить проверку что значение нулевое
}
```

Comment: Да просто `m_x_{},  m_y_{}`

Comment: Хм, т.е. `return m_x_ == __type{} && m_y_ == __type{};`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна [инициализация значением](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)?

```
template<typename T>
    struct Test
{
    Test():t{} {}
    T t;
    void out() { cout << t << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test<double>().out();
    Test<bool>().out();
    Test<int>().out();
}
```

Comment: Нет, мне нужно что бы в шаблоном методе `is_empty` я мог сверить переданный параметр на то что он пуст, т.е. содержит `0`,  но для каждого типа свой, не просто как `int`.

Comment: Что значит "содержит 0" для строки? Для потока? Для встроенных типов без конструкторов инициализация по значению дает 0, но раз она вам не нужна (я так понимаю, что по ссылке вы прочли и говорите обдуманно)... Кстати, я бы называл это `is_zero` или еще как-то, но говорить, что целое число пустое, если оно равно 0 - как-то даже странно :)

Comment: Я имею ввиду то что как я вас понял, и то что прочел, то я могу так выполнить проверку, и она вернет `true` если оба значения будут заполнены не мусором, или значениями, а как бы инициализированы нулем `return m_x_ == __type{} && m_y_ == __type{};`?

Comment: @ヒミコ Угу, все так.